# single script for scientific paper on github?

Tags: matlab, github, computer-science

I am posting this question despite it possibly being off-topic, since I can't find a better place to ask:

I am publishing a scientific paper and use some analysis code which I want to be publicly available. I wrote a general purpose analysis library (Matlab) and put it onto github. Then there is a little script that uses that library for the specific purpose of this very paper. What is the best way to publish that script?

I see the following options where to publish this script:

1. publish into a new repository with only one file which is referenced in the paper (isn't that an overkill?)
2. append analysis script as supplementary information to the paper (not very accessible and usable for other people)
3. add to the same repository as the library (does not make sense since the library is general purpose while the script is for a single specific purpose)

Happy about any feedback, re-directions or discussions.

Comment: create an "examples" folder in your githup repository and add one subfolder "this is an example how I computed the stuff for my paper..." and noone will notice the problem :)

Comment: If you want future readers to be able to replicate your results exactly, you should probably create either a new repo or a new branch (see my answer below), unless your main repo won't change in the future. In Matlab, I'd also use "demos" rather than "examples", as that is what MathWorks' toolboxes use for the most part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if the best method, but here's what I did with one of my own Matlab libraries, [SHCTools](https://github.com/horchler/SHCTools), to make it publicly available for a journal article:

1. Created [new branch](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository/) of the repository (as opposed to an entirely new repository). This way the two are co-located, but the paper-specific branch can remain stable allowing readers to replicate results even after the main repository changes significantly.
2. Added a notice to the main branch's README.md file linking to the new stable branch.
3. Added a folder to the new stable branch containing M-files that re-create the figures in may paper (you could do the same with examples).

Comment: Downvoter: please explain yourself. In what way is this answer lacking or "not useful"?

Comment: I've offset all of the downvotes.  It's an interesting question, and you've provided a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a script as a supplemental resource (perhaps inside an `examples` or `contrib` directory) would seem like an acceptable and reasonably standard arrangement.

For a free-standing script, perhaps consider publishing it as a [gist](https://gist.github.com); this is a secondary service of Github for simple standalone snippets.